# Why does sys.exit() subtract the total?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a task at hand to write a program to calculate the sum of numbers. This is a beginner python program. I have found two solutions for this exercise in which one is working perfectly well and other one is not. Sample output is not provided for this problem.

Here is the question:

> **Sum of Numbers**
>
> Write a program with a loop that asks the user to enter a series of positive numbers.The user should enter a negative number to signal the end of the series. After all the positive numbers have been entered, the program should display their sum.

Here is my working solution:

```
# Get a positive number
number = float(input('Enter a positive number: '))

# Set the accumulator
total = 0.0

# Test the condition, calculate total, and display result
while number > 0:
    total += number
    number = float(input('Enter a positive number: '))
else:
    print(f'Total is {total}')
    quit()
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter a positive number: 5
Enter a positive number: 6
Enter a positive number: 7
Enter a positive number: -1
Total is 18.0
```

This is my second attempt to learn to code. Before this, I read couple of chapters of automate boring stuff with python. From there, I remembered that I can use those functions in python such as quit(), sys.exit().

Here is my solution I implemented first that didn't work as expected:

```
import sys

# Set the accumulator
total = 0.0

# Process one or more data
while True:
    entered_number = float(input('Enter a positive number: '))
    total += entered_number

    # Display result and Terminate
    while entered_number < 0:
        print(f'Total is: {total}')
        sys.exit()
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter a positive number: 5
Enter a positive number: 6
Enter a positive number: 4
Enter a positive number: -2
Total is: 13.0
```

Even though, I only entered sys.exit(), because I'm using pycharm, it automatically imported sys module. Problem with this approach is it subtracted the total sum from the negative value I entered at the prompt when exiting from the program.

So, how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is not with the `sys` import. `sys.exit()` simply exits the python program. The issue here is that your adding the negative value to your total.
Lets break down your two programs.

The first program:

- starts by asking the user for an Integer, you indicate it should be positive.
- declares the float value total as `0.0`
- creates a loop to continuously ask the same question, as long as the input is above 0. If so, you add the value to your total.
- Once the program detects a negative value as an input, you print the total and quit the program

The second program:

- declares the float value total 0
- continuously loops asking the user for an input while adding the input to the total
- After the input has been added each time, it checks if the input was negative, if so you print the total and exit the program

Just by breaking down the code we begin to see some issues here, this is why I find it helpful to write pseudocode as a beginner before coding.

To answer your question: The problem is not that your using `sys` but that your adding the number to the total no matter that number was inputted before checking the value itself.

There are some other issues to address here as well.

- Firstly, the loop is never actually exited, the program is just forced shut. Instead a singular while loop with [if-statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) checking if the value is positive, if so, add the value to the total, otherwise break out of the loop and print the total.
- Get used to being more descriptive with your program. Always imagine that someone who has never seen your program before it reading the source code and are trying to understand everything that is happening. Instead of `Enter a positive number:`  I suggest something similar to the following.

```py
print("Enter A Positive Number To Add To The Total")
print("To Exit The Program, Enter Any Negative Value")
while True:
    number = input("Enter Number: ")
```

I suggest reading the python documentation for some of the basics before jumping into coding. It's important to understand what exactly you're doing and how you're doing it.